# How to backup my iPhone 4S contacts to a CD?

Tags: backup, iphone, contacts

Even though iTunes is backing up all my contacts while I'm syncing, the backup still exists on a computer. So I would like to make a backup on another physical medium, just in case my computer or iPhone gets destroyed, lost, stolen, etc....
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can export your contacts from the `Contacts` app, it will save them as a Address Book Backup file (`.abbu`). Once you do that, you can drop the file into a burn cd folder and burn the CD.

*File < Export < Contacts Archive*
Save as a file that you can easily identify. (Contacts-date.abbu)

This of course only works if you sync your iPhone's contacts to your Address 
Book app.

Comment: You seem to be making the assumption that the OP owns and syncs their iPhone with a Mac.

Comment: This being "Ask Different" Which seems mac centric, it seems prudent. What makes you think the OP syncs with anything but a mac when they ask a question here?

Comment: This site is about *all* Apple hardware and software :) They could sync with a PC and ask a question here, as long as they're talking about an iPhone. Why, the first related question to the right is about a Windows sync setup.

Comment: One thing you might want to add is that you can Command-A to select all of the cards and File > Export > Export vCard... This is definitely more compatible with other applications, whether it be Contacts, Outlook, Gmail, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to try is syncing with iCloud, which will back-up/copy your contacts (among other items on your iPhone) into the Cloud and you could access it anywhere where you have an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I use List.Up (www.listdotup.com) to backup/restore my iPhone contacts.

Each backup is timestamp, available in vCard format and can be download from List.Up Cloud.